# MVC controller action with url parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a GET action in a controller and it needs to accept a parameter. This is for an edit view so I pass in the id (which is of type Guid) to the action.

Currently my URL looks like

```
controller/Edit?ItemId=<Guid>
```

Is there a way to make the urls look a little prettier, like this?

```
controller/Edit/<Guid>
```

My action signature:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid ItemId)
```

My route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, putting `[FromRoute]` in the action signature should do it. I mean

`public ActionResult Edit([FromRoute]Guid id)`

In this case the `id` variable will contain the `<Guid>` part `controller/Edit/<Guid>` of the URL.

It is important, that the parameter name `id` should be the same as the route parameter name `{id}` in the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use attribute routing:

```
[Route("controller/edit/{ItemId}")]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid ItemId)
{ }
```

And then enable it where you register your routes:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```